# libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 error opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I'm trying to install opencv on my server. I ran:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

which worked successfully but then when I try to `import cv2` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried `apt-get install libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` but the package doesn't exist.

My guess is that because I'm running a VPS, the gtk libraries are not present. Any ideas on how to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing them?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried installing that particular package but it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's a library, not a package.

Comment: Your question is answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761589/installing-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-in-ubuntu-15-04/766300).

Comment: the link above does not work. Question still un-answered

Comment: apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761589/installing-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-in-ubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it was resolve by installing libgtk package.
Run this command;

```
apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```